# An anime where a girl with pink hair, half naked (or completely naked), with supernatural power making limbs explode in the first episode

Tags: elfen-lied

In the first episode, a girl with pink hair, half naked (or completely naked), with supernatural power makes limbs explode. In the first episode or the second one, she's embraced (?) by someone. If I remember correctly, she's mentally like a child, or really lacks communication abilities.

Any help would be much appreciated!

P.S. Sorry for the terrible description, it's just that I have vague memory about it.

Comment: Since this is getting attention as a hot network question, here is a link to the scene in question, if anyone is interested.  [Definitely NSFW](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFvhKxWumcc).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are talking about [**Elfen Lied**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elfen_Lied). It's really crazy, especially the first episode.

[image]

Comment: You had me at "Makes limbs explode"

Comment: Reading the title alone, I immediately knew this was Elfen Lied.  Such an iconic opening scene.